# No routes matched location - pero me renderiza el componente y funciona perfecto

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, routes

Estoy teniendo el warning de : No routes matched location, en las rutas de detail y form, y en las demas rutas de mi app no. el tema es que me lanza el warning pero tambien me renderiza el componente de manera exitosa con todas sus funciones, tengo entendido de que si habria match con la ruta no deberia renderizarla. que podria estar afectando? ya intente  30 maneras deferentes.
No es problema de typeo, en ese caso no me renderizaria las rutas...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que version de react-router estas usando?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.